# Server Error in '/' Application error with a WCF REST service using https

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to host a WCF REST service on an https server. The IIS manager on the server is configured property for the https port and my Web.config is configured properly. But, I just get this message "Server Error in '/' Application error" when pinging the URL. The URL matches the correct virtual directory which has been configured as an IIS application. It just doesn't resolve. I have another WCF service on this server that's running fine, but it's using basicHttpBinding since it's a soap service.

Can someone look at my RESTful web.Config and see if I've over looked something since there must be something wrong? This service works fine when deployed on my local machine using http without all the https config settings, but when deployed on another https server it doesn't work. There has to be something I'm missing. Tnx.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
      </appSettings>
      <!-- SQL connection settings -->
      <connectionStrings>
      </connectionStrings>
      <!--
        For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

        The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
          <system.Web>
            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
          </system.Web>
      -->
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <client/>

        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
          <mexHttpsBinding>
            <binding name="secureMexBinding"/>
          </mexHttpsBinding>
        </bindings>

        <behaviors>
          <!-- Required for json web service -->
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webBehavior">
              <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>

          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehaviors">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>

        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviors" name="RepoWebService.MasterRepoAPI">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="StatuteRepoWebService.IRepoWebService.MasterRepoAPI"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureMexBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
          </service>
        </services>
        <protocolMapping>
          <add scheme="https" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"/>
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Add <customErrors mode="Off"> to the system.web section of your config file. This will result in you being able to see what the actual error message is and you can then understand whats going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but adding <system.web> <customErrors mode="Off"/> </system.web> in the web.Config still produces the same Server Error in '/' Application.  Unfortunately, this made no difference.

Comment: Was there no extra information in the error message? Turing custom errors off wasn't to fix the problem, it was to get information on what the actual error is

Comment: Yeah, I realize that, but actually in doing this I've come to realize that my IT resource has probably not provided the correct endpoint to the IIS services on the server that's hosting the WCF service and that's why it's not resolving or giving more error information w/ this mod. I'll find out tomorrow though. Thanks for shedding some light on this =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem your service configuration file seems to me. It only supports Https protocol. There might some problems in the hosting environment.
we are supposed to provide a https binding in IIS binding module, then service address will be https://x.x.x.x:xxxxx/service1.svc
[image]
Besides, here is my simplified configuration which using the WCF4.5 new feature, Protocol Mapping. it supports both https and http.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-new 
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was good information especially w/ the site binding settings. I do have another question. Our IT dept takes forever to do something and if the https site bindings on the server are set to 8443, shouldn't the url of https://x.x.x.x:8443/ resolve to the IIS home screen? Or is there another setting on the server that I need to configure to open that port? In my case the https site binding is port 8443, but the https://x.x.x.x:8443/ w/ our ip address inserted doesn't resolve to the IIS home screen and this is why my /service1.svc endpoint doesn't resolve.

Comment: By default the url of x.x.x.x:8843 should be the directory of the website. It depends on the following configuration,    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
We could also enable it in IIS Directory Browsing feature.